# DocumentClient CreateDocumentQuery or ReadDocumentAsync both throwing exceptions as id not found, whereas the id is present

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Sample code to query a collection and retrieve a single document sporadically throwing exception as id not found.

Query:

```
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(“db_name”, “collection_name”, “id”);
var result = await Client.ReadDocumentAsync<T>(docUri);
```

Comment: You need to include the partition key value associated with the document when reading the document by id.

Comment: Yes, we do have it in the version of CreateDocumentQueryAsync passed using FeedOptions but still throws sporadic exceptions.

Comment: If CreateDocumentAsync throws a 404 it means the collection or database does not exist.